# Delegates should display text

Tags: c#

I have following code in c#:

```
public class FClass
{
    public delegate string Show(int n);

    public void ShowDelegate(Show SD)
    {
        SD(1);
    }
}

public class SClass
{
    static string ReturnString(int n)
    {
        return n.ToString();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FClass fclass = new FClass();
        FClass.Show show = new FClass.Show(ReturnString);
        Console.WriteLine(fclass.ShowDelegate(show));
    }
}
```

It should display "1", but it showed an error.

Comment: `ShowDelegate` doesn't `return` anything - What exactly do you think you are passing to `Console.WriteLine`?

Comment: What is the error? That's essential to include in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ShowDelegate()` function doesn't return any value. You would need it to return the value from the `SD` delegate:

```
public class FClass
{
    public delegate string Show(int n);
    public string ShowDelegate(Show SD)
    {
        return SD(1);
    }
}

public class SClass
{
    static string ReturnString(int n)
    {
        return n.ToString();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FClass fclass = new FClass();
        FClass.Show show = new FClass.Show(ReturnString);
        Console.WriteLine(fclass.ShowDelegate(show));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned by [Krypt1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2610466/krypt1), `ShowDelegate()` function doesn't return any value (void). You would need it to either return the value from the SD delegate or move the `Console.WriteLine` call to the `ShowDelegate` method:

```
public class FClass
{
    public delegate string Show(int n);
    public void ShowDelegate(Show SD)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(SD(1)); // <-- Show delegate text
    }
}
public class SClass
{
    static string ReturnString(int n)
    {
        return n.ToString();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        FClass fclass = new FClass();
        FClass.Show show = new FClass.Show(ReturnString);
        fclass.ShowDelegate(show);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```